# Activiti- boundary timer event throws exceptions when fired

Tags: timer, activiti, bpmn

I applied boundary timer event on user task, I added java class on service task class attribute but when a timer expired and triggered list of exceptions throws i.e class assigned to service task cannot found. although class exist on the class path. asyncExecutorActivate property is also enabled in activiti configuration

here is a code

BPMN

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <process id="timertest" name="timertest" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startEvent1"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="sid-9F95F9B8-6C5C-4221-B3A7-3BD2BAEC22CA"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-08270597-3D34-4CFD-BACF-CB95036CBC48" sourceRef="startEvent1" targetRef="sid-9F95F9B8-6C5C-4221-B3A7-3BD2BAEC22CA"></sequenceFlow>
    <boundaryEvent id="sid-5AC91A08-17CC-4F6E-ABC2-2B8AF63EAB66" attachedToRef="sid-9F95F9B8-6C5C-4221-B3A7-3BD2BAEC22CA" cancelActivity="true">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDate>${expiresOn}</timeDate>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <endEvent id="sid-1D6E7697-6ECA-42BA-98E5-BE089A78DCF2"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-A4C68C9C-38C3-43A9-BB3F-83FABACA65F9" sourceRef="sid-CE624FA0-9F7E-4FF9-BF3E-C016D046A3BF" targetRef="sid-1D6E7697-6ECA-42BA-98E5-BE089A78DCF2"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="sid-CE624FA0-9F7E-4FF9-BF3E-C016D046A3BF" activiti:class="com.softech.workflowengine.workflow.policyack.servicetask.TimerClass"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-799456B9-F667-4E98-A856-E1AA7B79F680" sourceRef="sid-5AC91A08-17CC-4F6E-ABC2-2B8AF63EAB66" targetRef="sid-CE624FA0-9F7E-4FF9-BF3E-C016D046A3BF"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="sid-705703CA-B642-435C-8393-B236EC3E964B"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-010B8977-34F9-40F4-B694-D56D5BA34257" sourceRef="sid-9F95F9B8-6C5C-4221-B3A7-3BD2BAEC22CA" targetRef="sid-705703CA-B642-435C-8393-B236EC3E964B"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_timertest">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="timertest" id="BPMNPlane_timertest">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startEvent1" id="BPMNShape_startEvent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="100.0" y="163.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-9F95F9B8-6C5C-4221-B3A7-3BD2BAEC22CA" id="BPMNShape_sid-9F95F9B8-6C5C-4221-B3A7-3BD2BAEC22CA">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="175.0" y="138.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-5AC91A08-17CC-4F6E-ABC2-2B8AF63EAB66" id="BPMNShape_sid-5AC91A08-17CC-4F6E-ABC2-2B8AF63EAB66">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="31.0" width="31.0" x="253.59371010330312" y="202.75947444214634"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-1D6E7697-6ECA-42BA-98E5-BE089A78DCF2" id="BPMNShape_sid-1D6E7697-6ECA-42BA-98E5-BE089A78DCF2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="28.0" width="28.0" x="405.0" y="311.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-CE624FA0-9F7E-4FF9-BF3E-C016D046A3BF" id="BPMNShape_sid-CE624FA0-9F7E-4FF9-BF3E-C016D046A3BF">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="210.0" y="285.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-705703CA-B642-435C-8393-B236EC3E964B" id="BPMNShape_sid-705703CA-B642-435C-8393-B236EC3E964B">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="28.0" width="28.0" x="320.0" y="164.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-A4C68C9C-38C3-43A9-BB3F-83FABACA65F9" id="BPMNEdge_sid-A4C68C9C-38C3-43A9-BB3F-83FABACA65F9">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="310.0" y="325.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="405.0" y="325.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-799456B9-F667-4E98-A856-E1AA7B79F680" id="BPMNEdge_sid-799456B9-F667-4E98-A856-E1AA7B79F680">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="269.5937101033031" y="234.75947444214634"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="269.5937101033031" y="259.3797372210732"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="260.0" y="259.3797372210732"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="260.0" y="285.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-08270597-3D34-4CFD-BACF-CB95036CBC48" id="BPMNEdge_sid-08270597-3D34-4CFD-BACF-CB95036CBC48">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="130.0" y="178.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="175.0" y="178.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-010B8977-34F9-40F4-B694-D56D5BA34257" id="BPMNEdge_sid-010B8977-34F9-40F4-B694-D56D5BA34257">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="275.0" y="178.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="320.0" y="178.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Java Delegate

```
package com.softech.workflowengine.workflow.policyack.servicetask;

import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

public class TimerClass implements JavaDelegate{

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        System.out.println(">> in TimerClass ");

    }
}
```

Exception

```
07:56:03,977 [activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext  - Error while closing command context
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't instantiate class com.softech.workflowengine.workflow.policyack.servicetask.TimerClass
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.instantiate(ReflectUtil.java:137)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.defaultInstantiateDelegate(ClassDelegate.java:306)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.instantiateDelegate(ClassDelegate.java:295)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.getActivityBehaviorInstance(ClassDelegate.java:273)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.execute(ClassDelegate.java:217)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.executeActivityBehavior(ContinueProcessOperation.java:180)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.executeSynchronous(ContinueProcessOperation.java:131)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.continueThroughFlowNode(ContinueProcessOperation.java:89)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.run(ContinueProcessOperation.java:55)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.executeOperation(CommandInvoker.java:73)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.executeOperations(CommandInvoker.java:57)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:42)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.TransactionContextInterceptor.execute(TransactionContextInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:29)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:44)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:39)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ExecuteAsyncRunnable.executeJob(ExecuteAsyncRunnable.java:97)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ExecuteAsyncRunnable.run(ExecuteAsyncRunnable.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiClassLoadingException: Class not found: com.softech.workflowengine.workflow.policyack.servicetask.TimerClass
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:87)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.instantiate(ReflectUtil.java:134)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.softech.workflowengine.workflow.policyack.servicetask.TimerClass
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:288)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:68)
    ... 25 more
07:56:04,000 [activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ExecuteAsyncRunnable  - Job 130011 failed
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't instantiate class com.softech.workflowengine.workflow.policyack.servicetask.TimerClass
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.instantiate(ReflectUtil.java:137)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.defaultInstantiateDelegate(ClassDelegate.java:306)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.instantiateDelegate(ClassDelegate.java:295)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.getActivityBehaviorInstance(ClassDelegate.java:273)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.execute(ClassDelegate.java:217)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.executeActivityBehavior(ContinueProcessOperation.java:180)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.executeSynchronous(ContinueProcessOperation.java:131)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.continueThroughFlowNode(ContinueProcessOperation.java:89)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.agenda.ContinueProcessOperation.run(ContinueProcessOperation.java:55)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.executeOperation(CommandInvoker.java:73)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.executeOperations(CommandInvoker.java:57)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:42)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.TransactionContextInterceptor.execute(TransactionContextInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:29)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:44)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:39)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ExecuteAsyncRunnable.executeJob(ExecuteAsyncRunnable.java:97)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ExecuteAsyncRunnable.run(ExecuteAsyncRunnable.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Bean Initialization

```
@Bean
    public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration() throws Exception {
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration engineConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();

        engineConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSource);
        engineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        engineConfiguration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        engineConfiguration.setAsyncExecutorActivate(true);
        return engineConfiguration;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the thread that requires the class in the classpath is activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2], which leads to the question where are you running the job executor? How are you making sure that the class is in the classpath?

Comment: My application is spring application and I enabled job executor in configuration class see my edited post how I enable executor

Comment: I am a beginner dont know whether to configure job executor separately

Answer (score 0):

The classes need to be executed after the timer expired must be on tomcat's classpath (in tomcat's lib folder). For more reference please see article

https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-devoxx-activiti-bpmn